# A namespace cannot directly contain members?

Tags: c#

I have a problem. I have been following a tutorial, so that I could learn programming with Xamarin. Well now I have this error line, that I have written in the title. Here's the code for you all;

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using UIKit;

namespace freesongsforme
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    { 
        var listView = new ListView();
        var myTrainers = new ObservableCollection<string>() 
        { 
            "Song 1",
            "Song 2",       
        };

        listView.ItemsSource = mySongs; 

        myTrainers.Add("Songsr");
    }
```

The ''main'' part is marked as an error.

Comment: `Class` is missing from your code.

Comment: C# is object-oriented language. At least *one* object must be created as an absolute minimum for C# console app to run (and it should contain entry point which is `static void Main()`)

Answer (score 13):

your code needs to be contained within a `Class`

```
namespace freesongsforme
{

  public class MyClass {

    static void Main(string[] args)
    { 
      var listView = new ListView();
      var myTrainers = new ObservableCollection<string>() { 

        "Song 1",
        "Song 2",

      };

    listView.ItemsSource = mySongs; 

    myTrainers.Add("Songsr");

  }
}
```