# site.master A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to finish this website project, got everything fixed besides this:

```
namespace MillerDylanTwoColumn
{


protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    var lbl = sender as Label;
    lbl.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
  }

}
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Put your code in a `class`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A namespace cannot directly contain members?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37592507/a-namespace-cannot-directly-contain-members)

Comment: Hi, that fixed the error somehow (I tried before and it didn't.) But now it says: 
    A default document is not configured for the requested URL, and directory browsing is not enabled on the server.
 What did I miss?

Comment: That I do not have an answer to, I'm afraid.

Comment: Not to be a turd but looking at the issue, hearing your new issue, and then telling us you have a website project... I think you're diving too far too fast.  It's the best way to learn, IMO, but I'd take a few steps back and grab a book or two and work on the  basics.  If you do and look back you'll see what I'm saying.  If not then I still encourage you to keep going and best of luck :)

Comment: Page Load should be inside `public partial class MyPage : System.Web.UI.Page { }`